# How will I be able to write a function which allows to compare a selected file to another file to detect the similarity

Tags: python, html, flask

I want to create a web page, such as the interface contains a button to select file from directory and i want to compare the file selected will the files that i have in a folder of project
using python and flask

```
compare/
    main.py
    folder/
        file1.pdf
        file2.pdf
        file3.pdf
        file4.pdf
    templates/
            importfile.html
```

I tried with this one but it doesn't work as I want:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
with open('file1.pdf', errors='ignore')as file1, open('file3.pdf', errors='ignore')as file2:
    file_1_data = file1.read()
    file_2_data = file2.read()
    similarity = SequenceMatcher(None, file_1_data, file_2_data).ratio()
    s = similarity*100
    print(s)
```

Someone to help me? I really need to solve this in a short time

Comment: Can you explain what does "compare" mean? Do you want to find the difference line by line, or do you just care if the files differ at all? Is a function is_same(file) that returns True, False for some file enough?

Comment: witch returns the similarity rate, by percentage

Comment: You need to be a little more clearn on what you want to accomplish. The similarity rate is something not defined. How do you consider similarity? By matching english words? Then you should consider using NLP, matching lines as strings? There are a number of libraries and algorithms that do that and each one has a different similarity score.

Comment: I want to do a plagiarism detection by comparing the add file, to a folder that contains pdf or txt files

Comment: Ok your code works for txt files. There is an issue though. You pass the whole file as a string with newlines etc.  This is not really ideal, since you want to do plagiarism checks you proably need to do some custom splitting (i.e sentences, newlines etc). And again this is not trivial. Probably your best option is to go with something that uses NLP. For pdf files it will not work, because pdf is not a normal text file. If you open a pdf file with a text editor all you see is encoded data. In order to do the ratio with Sequencematcher you need to use a library that is able to read from a pdf.